# How can I solve my problem by jupyter run programs

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Whenever I started run projects in `jupyter`, It give me an error **:**

> Unreadable Notebook:  NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON:
> '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<html lang...")

Or sometime give me this error when I am trying to upload a project **:**

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 6

How can I solve these errors ?

Comment: can you please add the code, explain the question in a better way, show the error ?
No one can understand this question as it is, please add more details.

Comment: I tried to open, some ipynb files in jupyter,but, all of them give me these errors. And I remember, these errors from files, not codes

Comment: can you try to open it in notepad and try to share it ? maybe its code issue so we need to see the code once.

Comment: this file
https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/tools_matplotlib.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when you click on download button for the given file, it shows you the json of the notebook, you probably downloaded it and tried to run the file.
I don't know why it does that, but the solution is,
There's an option called open in colab, you can open the notebook in google colab or kaggle from the link, download the notebook and run the code on your own machine.
Hope this solves your problem !

Comment: I tried this way and result was good.

thank u